# Is there comparison in python which returns int?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to compare tuples a = (a1, a2, a3) and b = (b1, b2, b3) and use following result:

1. -1 in the case of a < b
2. 0 in the case of a == b
3. 1 in the case of a > b

Is there builtin function which allows to do this?

Comment: So you want the `cmp()` function, which was removed from Python 3. Why do you need this?

Comment: See [Why is the cmp parameter removed from sort/sorted in Python3.0?](//stackoverflow.com/q/20202418)

Comment: @MartijnPieters, it is just for educational purposes. I am just learning python

Comment: Then why are you asking us to do this for you? Try things yourself and ask questions about specific details you got stuck with.